# Burninate or convert the visual-c#

Tags: support, tags

There's a [visual-c#](/questions/tagged/visual-c%23). It's probably not ever used in the sense that it means. It should be burninated or converted to c#. 20 questions are in this tag.

Comment: and most of them by a single user (with 2 accounts)

Comment: Are they really the same? "c#" may apply to web apps or desktop apps or just general code, while "visual c#" could tag more specifically to desktop apps through visual studio...

Comment: @Michael I assume you are referring to visual C# express edition, which focuses on desktop? Well, in the ***very few*** questions cited, that is ***not*** how they were being used. In general, C# is a more useful marker, in real terms.

Comment: @MichaelJasper That distinction did not appear in the questions. The majority of the questions were more of the "Me have problem, you fix" variety.

Comment: @MarcGravell Good spotting on the duplicate accounts. Out of curiosity, do those get merged systematically, when discovered?

Comment: @MPelletier not if they are inactive unregistered accounts - no real point. With active users, sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the technology! done and done. Additionally, a synonym is now in effect, to prevent reappearance.